# how to get vm permissions in vijava

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere, esxi

I'm trying to get permissions of virtual machine using vijava like this:

```
ManagedEntity me = new
InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("VirtualMachine", vmName);
                VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) me;
for (Permission permission : vm.getPermission()) {
                System.out.println(permission.getPrincipal());
}
```

With this I get permissions applied only for This vm.

How can I get total permissions on virtual machine including inherited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all inherited permissions you should get all parents permissions like this:

```
  while (me.getParent() != null) {
        me = me.getParent();
        Permission[] permissions = me.getPermission();
        if (permissions != null) {
            for (Permission p : permissions) {
                // do stuff....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible, because each list of permissions is associated with a specific entity (i.e. VirtualMachine, HostSystem, etc..).

The way I'd do this is I'd get the underlying entities for the virtual machine and get their permissions as well. For example, since you have the VirtualMachine object, get the underlying HostSystem and retrieve it's permissions, and so on.

```
ManagedEntity me = new
InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("VirtualMachine", vmName);
                VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) me;

// Assuming that you have a ServiceInstance object si.
HostSystem host = (HostSystem)MorUtil.createExactManagedEntity(si
                        .getServerConnection(),vm.getRuntime().host);
Permission[] hostPermissions = host.getPermission();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `host.getPermission()` returns `null` ((  Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have permissions added to the host. I just tried it, yea `getPermission()` returns null for the host if there were no permissions added. When I go to vSphere Client, View Hosts, Right Click on the Host and then Add Permission, after I add the permission then `getPermission()` won't be null and would actually contain the details of that permission.